# Keyboard shortcut for breakpoints in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio

My software is full of breakpoints due to debugging. I want to delete every breakpoint. Can someone tell me the keyboard shortcut to view all breakpoints in visual studio?

Answer (score 0):

Under Debug menu you can enable/disable/delete all breakdowns.
I don't think there is a shortcut in Visual Studio Code but If I remember right in visual studio (the full version) the shortcut is CTRL + SHIFT + F9.

Answer (score 0):

In `codium` version 1.49.3 it's:
Run->Remove_all_breakpoints

It's not key bounded.